# Google Maps V3 API and MarkerManager - How to toggle selected Markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markermanager

I am using the actual google maps api v3. In my map, I have some Markers. For displaying my markes, I am using the MarkerManager.js.

Each marker has an attribute "type" (a number between 1 and 5).

On my site I have some radiobuttons.

```
 <input type="radio" name="display_marker" value="0" checked> All
 <input type="radio" name="display_marker" value="1" checked> 1
 <input type="radio" name="display_marker" value="2" checked> 2
 <input type="radio" name="display_marker" value="3" checked> 3
 <input type="radio" name="display_marker" value="4" checked> 4
 <input type="radio" name="display_marker" value="5" checked> 5
```

On selecting value=0, I want to show all markers. Selecting value=1, I want to show only the markers whose type beeing 1 and so on.

When creating my markermanager array I do following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.135789, 11.579075);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
        setupMarkers();
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });

});



        function setupMarkers(){
            mgr = new MarkerManager(map);

            var mc = myobject.length;
            google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function(){
                mgr.addMarkers(createMarkers(mc), 11);
                mgr.refresh();
            });
        }


        function createMarkers(nn){
            var batch = [];

            for(var ii = 0; ii < nn; ii++){

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: getLatLng(ii),
                    title: "marker " + ii,
                    type: getType(ii),
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                    alert("title:" + this.title + "\ntype: " + this.type);
                });

                batch.push(marker);
            }
            return batch;
        }
```

What do I have to do in my show_marker(val) function?

```
$("#myid input").click(function(){
  show_marker($(this).attr('value'));
});

function show_marker(val){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem using multiple marker managers.
All markers with type=1 go to manager1, all markers with type=2 go to manager2 and so on.

Now I can show all markermanages and show/hide them onclick (managerX.hide() )